# Select distinct all records by date in descending order for each table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2014

I have a database model like this:

[image: Database Model]

*Each user has many projects. Each project has many versions. Each version has many requirements. Each requirement has many pos (part-of-speech).*

I want to select all of the `POS_NAME` by distinct from all requirements exist in Requirement entity but based on the newest `VERSION_DATE` for each project and each user too.

How am I supposed to query this in Ms. SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would improve this question a lot.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Also provide what you need on output.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know what exactly you need in result set, I show you general approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.POS_NAME --here put all columns you need
FROM POS p
INNER JOIN Requirement r
    ON r.ID_REQ = p.ID_REQ
INNER JOIN Version v
    ON v.ID_VERSION = r.ID_VERSION
INNER JOIN (SELECT  VERSION_NAME,
                    MAX(VERSION_DATE) as VERSION_DATE
            FROM Version) as v1
    ON v1.VERSION_NAME = v.VERSION_NAME AND v1.VERSION_DATE = v.VERSION_DATE
INNER JOIN Project pr
    ON pr.ID_PROJECT = v.ID_PROJECT
INNER JOIN User u
    ON u.ID_USER = p.ID_USER
```